# Reading characters from file into list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I have a part of a program with the following code

```
file1 = [line.strip()for line in open(sometext.txt).readlines()] 
print ((file1)[0])
```

and when the code is executed it gives me the whole contents of the txt file which is a very long sentence,
how would I go about reading every letter and placing it in a list to index each character separately? I have used the list() function which seems to put the whole text file into a list and not each character.

Comment: You can use index to get char from text  - ex. `"hello world!"[0]`. If you need list then use `list("hello world!")`

Comment: btw: your code doesn't print full text from file but only first line. To print first char in first line you need `print(file1[0][0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `read()` is enough. Plus. if you want to store the list without `\n` and white spaces, you can use:

```
char_list = [ch for ch in open('test.txt').read() if ch != '\n' if ch != ' ']
```

You can remove the `if` statements if you want to maintain them.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `file.read()` rather than `file.readlines()`:

```
file1 = [char for char in open(sometext.txt).read()]
```

You don't really need list-comprehension, however;  instead you can do this:

```
file1 = list(open(sometext.txt).read())
```

Also, as @furas mentioned in his comment, you don't need a list to have indexing.  `str` also has a method called `index`, so you could say `file1 = open(sometext.txt).read()` and still be able to use `file1.index()`.  Note, `str` also has a `find` method which will return -1 if the substring is not found, rather than raising a ValueError.