# Why is there an error trying to make a list into an intereger in python

Tags: python, file, math

Hello I'm unable to find out why I'm not able to make this list an int so I can get sum the first 10 numbers. Do you know another way or the fix to my way:

```
#This problem is definetely posibble
#Sourcing help on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343829/reading-characters-from-file-into-list    (Python 2.7, Works on Python 3.11)

data = [ch for ch in open('/Users/bodhimate/Desktop/Coding/Math/projectEuler/projectEulerDoc13.txt').read() if ch != '\n' if ch != '']
int(data[0, 10000000])
sum(data[0,9])
```

I've tried using the int() method and then the sum() method but I think the problem is the way I'm obtaining the list. I expected it to just give me the answer to the sum of the first ten numbers of the file (which are in this link: https://projecteuler.net/problem=13)

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you doing Project Euler when you haven't even figured out how to read an integer from a file?  You're out of your depth.

Comment: A tuple is not a valid index for a list. Did you mean, e.g., `data[0:9]` instead of `data[0,9]`?

Comment: “Making a list an int” is a premise that makes no sense. Don’t you rather mean *make each item of the list an int*? And do you see how your code doesn’t do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert to int inside the for loop

Also to only use the first 10 values of a list,
you can use data[:10]

```py
path = '/Users/bodhimate/Desktop/Coding/Math/projectEuler/projectEulerDoc13.txt'
data = [int(ch) for ch in open(path).read() if ch != '\n' if ch != '']
print(sum(data[:10]))
```

Also, do note that python can use relative path*, meaning if your python file is in the same folder as projectEulerDoc13.txt, you can just set the path to:
`'projectEulerDoc13.txt'`

Comment: *"python can use relative import"* - That's something different. You're talking about a relative **path**. *"if your python file is in the same folder"* - No, it doesn't matter where the Python file is, it matters what the **working directory** is.

Comment: [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory/66860904)

Answer (score 0):

If you have that file you linked there is no need to check for invalid chars when getting just the first 10 numbers.

Modifying your code, printing the sum of the first 10 digits:

```
with open(path,'r') as infile:
  data = [int(ch) for i, ch in enumerate(infile.read()) if i < 10]
print(sum(data))
```